# A brief proof of Convexity.

Tags: real-analysis

*Given* $f(x,y) = \sqrt{1 + x^2 + y^2}$, *prove that $f(x,y)$ is convex. Try to do this without using the Hessian*.

Answer (score 6):

Let $z = (x,y)$,

$$f(z)=\left\| \begin{array}{c} z \\ 1\end{array}\right\|$$

\begin{align}f(\lambda z_1 + (1-\lambda) z_2) &= \left\| \begin{array}{c} \lambda z_1 + (1-\lambda)z_2 \\ 1\end{array}\right\| \\
&= \left\| \begin{array}{c} \lambda z_1 + (1-\lambda)z_2 \\ \lambda+(1-\lambda)\end{array}\right\| \\&\leq \lambda f(z_1)+(1-\lambda)f(z_2)\end{align}

by triangle inequality.

Comment: Very simple and direct proof!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the definition of convexity directly, i.e., to prove that 
$$f\big(\lambda(x_1,y_1) + (1 - \lambda)(x_2, y_2)\big) \leq \lambda ~f(x_1,y_1) + (1-\lambda)~f(x_2, y_2)$$
Based on the basic algebraic calculation, plus the note that:
$$ 2x_1x_2y_1y_2 \leq x_1^2y_2^2 + x_2^2y_1^2 $$

Comment: This should be posted as a remark, not as a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is clearly continuous, in order to prove convexity it is enough to show the midpoint-convexity, i.e. the inequality
$$\sqrt{1+a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{1+c^2+d^2}\geq \sqrt{4+\left(a+c\right)^2+\left(b+d\right)^2} \tag{1}$$
that boils down to

$$\sqrt{(1+a^2+b^2)(1+c^2+d^2)} \geq 1+ac+bd \tag{2} $$
that is a straightforward consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Graphically. The contour curves: $$x^2+y^2=z^2-1$$ are circles with the radius $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ :

[image]

As the lower contour set is convex, $z$ is a convex function.